# What are the reasons why it isn't saving the year?

Tags: php

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czofT.png)I have a problem in putting the school_year(syearid). I have to put the year automatically in the vote.php how to do it?  Am I right to do this? There is a picture what my data struc. looks like

Here's my code:

```
$idnum=$_POST['idnum'];
$stat='voted';

$sqla = "UPDATE student 
    SET status=?
    WHERE idno=?";

$qa = $db->prepare($sqla);
$qa->execute(array($stat,$idnum));

$edittable=$_POST['votes'];
$a=1;
$N = count($edittable);
$YearNow=Date('Y');

//making an option 
echo '<label class="control-label col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">School Year</label>';
echo '<select  name="syearid" class="select2_group form-control"  style="text-align:center;" >';
echo'<optgroup label="School Year" style="text-align:center;">';
echo '<?php';

date("Y");
include('../connection/connect.php');

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM school_year");
$result->bindParam(':syearid', $res);
$result->execute();
for ($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++) {
    $isSelected = ((date("Y") == $row['from_year']) ? " selected" : "");
    echo "<option value='".$row['syearid']."'$isSelected>".$row['from_year'].'-'.$row['to_year']."</option>";
    echo'?>';
    echo'</optgroup>';
    echo'</select>';

    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE candidates,student,school_year 
            SET votes=votes+?
            WHERE candid =? AND school_year.syearid = candidates.syearid  AND school_year.from_year like $YearNow  ";

        $q = $db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($a,$edittable[$i]));      

        $sqlas = "INSERT INTO studentvotes(candid,idno,syearid) VALUES (:m,:n,:o)";
        $qs = $db->prepare($sqlas);
        //this is where my problem is how to put the selected year in another mysql?
        $qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>$isSelected));
    }
}

header("location: notification.php?". http_build_query($query));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: I have no errors but when I look to my database the syearid will not save, the result was 0 it should be like 2000

Comment: what is data type of this field?@zeyzey

Comment: I don't understand: `...(candid,idno,syearid) VALUES (:m,:n,:o)` then `':o'=>$isSelected`. Are you sure? **You're not writing a date there**.

Comment: ':o'=>$isSelected means that in $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM school_year");
$result->bindParam(':syearid', $res);
for ($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++) {
    $isSelected = ((date("Y") == $row['from_year']) ? " selected" : "");
    echo "<option value='".$row['syearid']."'$isSelected>".$row['from_year'].'-'.$row['to_year']."</option>";
    echo'?>';  echo'</optgroup>';
    echo'</select>';..I don't know if it will be save the automatically?., it's like that if the computer year is 2016 then it will automatically put the year and save it like that school_year id under of that year

Comment: @zeyzey no, check that line. isSelected will be an empty string or " selected" but never a valid date. I don't know what you need, it may be date("Y") or $row['from_year'] or something else but not what it is now.

Comment: actually I can do like this , $YearNow=Date('Y'); then  $qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>$Yearnow));. It will be save the year but I want that the id under that year will be save . Example year is 2015 then if I submit it , database will store the id not the year

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to insert a string in `syearid` field(" selected" or empty string).

```
...
$isSelected = ((date("Y") == $row['from_year']) ? " selected" : "");
...
$sqlas = "INSERT INTO studentvotes(candid,idno,syearid) VALUES (:m,:n,:o)";
...
$qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>$isSelected));
```

I suppose, the passed value should be type of `INT` or `DATE`(depends on field type)

Comment: passing empty string to INT field results to "0"

Comment: I would like that instead of the from_year will be save I want to be save the id of that from_year. The result is 0 don't know why

Comment: What should I do for that?

Comment: just pass (int) $row['from_year'] into query params: $qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>(int) $row['from_year']));